# Redirect to Notification Access Settings

Tags: android

I'm currently developing an app for Android that uses the `NotificationListenerService`,  which requires that the user will enable notification access for my app under `Setting -> Security -> Notification Access`.

My question is that can I redirect the user to this place so they will enable it? So far I only managed to direct them to `Setting -> Security` window.

Also, is it possible to first check if the user enabled notification access for my app already and only then redirect them?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can open the `NotificationAccessSettingsActivity` by using the following `Intent`, but I'm not sure about checking to see if they've already enabled your app.

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

**Alternatively, for API 22+:**

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If someone knows if I can find out if the user enabled my app I'd appreciate it

Comment: It is possible to access the list of notification listeners, which allows to to check if your app is one of them:

`private boolean isNotificationServiceRunning() {
  ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
  String enabledNotificationListeners = Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners");
  String packageName = getPackageName();

  return enabledNotificationListeners != null && enabledNotificationListeners.contains(packageName);
 }`

Comment: if you are like me and would prefer to use the constant, its Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS

Comment: @hapticdata Ah, nice. Looks like that was added in API 22.

Comment: I m always getting false value in nexus 5, API 23, even after giving permissions.

Comment: @Panache to CHECK for permissions, you should use: `NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled()` which works after API-19. Before it will always return true.

Comment: How to open this settings page only for a specific app, such that only one specific app is in the list to enable it. We can achieve similar thing for `android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` by setting app's package name like so: `new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS, "app's package name")`

Answer (score 5):

Many Thanks to @adneal and @Waboodoo. I am posting this for an complete answer

Check permission granted or not using this method

```
private boolean isNotificationServiceRunning() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    String enabledNotificationListeners =
            Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners");
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    return enabledNotificationListeners != null && enabledNotificationListeners.contains(packageName);
}
```

Then show settings activity, if necessary

```
boolean isNotificationServiceRunning = isNotificationServiceRunning();
if(!isNotificationServiceRunning){
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
}
```

Comment: For a simpler way to check if access is granted you can also use: `NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(context).contains(context.packageName)` (see [henrichg's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185207/4464562))

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the notification manager to check if notifications are enabled at the OS level:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
```