# Android 7.0/API24: How to check for notification access (Settings.Secure.enabled_notification_listeners)

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

In Android 6.0/API23 and earlier, the following used to work:

```
String settingEnabled = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners");
```

In Android 7.0 Nougat/API24 this seems to be no longer supported, because the code above returns `null`.

It actually was never mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html

How do we check if our app has notification access in Android 7.0 Nougat API24?

Edit: It seems that actually that after you first gained the access in the settings, the code above returns the correct state. But not on the initial request after installation.

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
Set<String> packageNames = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages (context);
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Amazing how little documentation there is around this. There is no API in the Android SDK, but the support library provides the workaround haha.