# How to Open Notification center from Application

Tags: android, android-settings

I am using following code to open Application settings, but I need to open Notification center from my application.Is it possible to open Notification center from the application? If so, Please guide a way to do so.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to Notification Access Settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663359/redirect-to-notification-access-settings)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS
```

Documentation says ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS)):

> Activity Action: Show Notification listener settings.
>
> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you
>   safeguard against this.